# Copy Jump List Shortcuts to Disk

Tags: windows-7, powershell, jump-list

Is there a way to copy Window 7 Jump List Shortcuts or File Names to disk?

Can Powershell be used?

I want to do this because my Jump List keeps getting cleared out like mentioned in this posting:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/8e3c2a80-392d-44e2-8b9f-6eb5deb9a1e1

If I can back up the Shortcuts or File Names, then I will at least know what files I need to add back to the Jump List when it gets cleared out.

Comment: I am impressed with Stackoverflow. I just posted this question 5 minutes ago and it is already coming back in Google search results. At first, I thought someone else was having the same problem. lol

Comment: That's more a result of Google aggressively indexing this site as new content appears quite often.

Comment: Thanks for the comment fenster. The answer given on this question points me to a directory that have file names that are GUIDs and the content is binary. It is not very useful for what I want to do, which is being able to get a list of files that are in the Jump List. So I cannot select this as the answer to my question. I did give a upvote for giving an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Jump list files are located in %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations and %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations.  If the files are copied in the folder, the jump list items will appear again.

Powershell can, indeed, be used to copy the files to a backup destination and then be copied back when desirable.

If you wish to keep your jump list from being cleared, you may want to make sure Recent files are not cleared from your system.